# MySQL REGEXP + whitespace (\s)

Tags: mysql, regex, json

The database I work with stores JSON entries in LONGTEXT datatypes. I want to be able to SELECT entries depending on the JSON data. Here's some example data:

```
 {
    "12f9cb0a-2218-4590-a05d-c1ffab00f693":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": "test"
        }
    },
    "4d1dfd2e-7bc1-4303-9c8c-90856e918bb9":  {
        "item":  {
            "0": "11"
        }
    }
 }
```

So I want to select data that contains **"4d1dfd2e-7bc1-4303-9c8c-90856e918bb9":  { "item": { "0":"11" } }** by filtering out the whitespace (tabs, spaces, new lines) using the REGEXP function, I have tried this to no avail:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (elements REGEXP BINARY '"4d1dfd2e-7bc1-4303-9c8c-90856e918bb9":\s*{\s*"item":\s*{\s*"0":\s*"11"\s*}\s*}');
```

The regex test works using Rubular and Regexpal.com but MYSQL doesn't seem to like the **\s*** expression. Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Before MySQL 8.0**, MySQL regexes only support the notations listed in [§12.7.2 "Regular Expressions" of the *MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax) (or counterpart for the appropriate version), which include the `[[:space:]]` notation but not the `\s` notation. So, you just need to replace each occurrence of `\s` with `[[:space:]]`.

**In MySQL 8.0 and later**, MySQL uses the regex support of International Components for Unicode [[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax)], which does include `\s` [[link](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)]; but because MySQL itself uses `\` as the escape character within strings, you need to double the backslash, replacing each occurrence of `\s` with `\\s`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a C escape sequence that handles tabs, spaces AND new lines? (an alternative to \s)

Comment: Re-read that, the query still returns nothing :(. It breaks from '"4d1dfd2e-7bc1-4303-9c8c-90856e918bb9":\\s*'... '"4d1dfd2e-7bc1-4303-9c8c-90856e918bb9":\\s*{' doesn't work

Comment: I googled around a bit and found that you can escape curly brackets by using **{{** but this still does not work.

Comment: @TommyPlummer: Does `'"4d1dfd2e-7bc1-4303-9c8c-90856e918bb9":[[:space:]]*\\{'` work any better?

Comment: Fantastic, it now works! I changed the regex string to **"4d1dfd2e-7bc1-4303-9c8c-90856e918bb9":[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*"item":  {[[:space:]]*"0": "11"[[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*}** to pull the tables successfully. It seems the curly brackets did not need the \\ escape characters (it seemed to actually break the query). Thanks again!

Comment: @TommyPlummer: You're welcome! Though it means that my answer was actually totally wrong. I need to fix it now. :-P

Comment: Mysql does support `\s`. You just need to use double - backslash `\\s`

Comment: @MatthiasGwiozda: Thanks for your downvote. This answer is from more than seven years ago; it should not surprise you that MySQL has features now that it did not have then.

Comment: Yeah, right. Would be nice if you could edit your answer and write a info that it's now possible (if it's really because of the version difference). Could be confusing for people that read your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use string replace;

```
select replace(json, ' ','') from table;
```

If your data has spaces in it, this won't work.

Comment: after you added query, ruakh posts an excellent answer.  read his.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use json type:

`` SELECT CAST(`column` AS JSON)
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(CAST(`column` as JSON),'$."4d1dfd2e-7bc1-4303-9c8c-90856e918bb9".item."0"')="11" ``