# Regex to filter string with special characters excluding hyphen, period and spaces in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to check a name column in SQL to make sure it does not have any special characters in it. But the names are allowed to have spaces in between, hyphens, `,period (.) in them.

Example

**Valid names:**

Brad

Brad-Tom

Brad Cooper

Brade`

Brad.Cooper

**Invalid names:**

Br@ad

Brad#

The regular expression I used to match it:
select name regex '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s.`-]'
but this does not seem to work for all the uses cases in SQL

Comment: say what use cases your attempt did not work for

Comment: do you count `Albrecht Dürer` as having a special character?

Comment: names with spaces and hyphens are getting selected using ^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.`-]
Also this is databricks sql

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  having the - at the end of the class works when I try it https://dbfiddle.uk/rFEsq7UI

Comment: @ysth replacing \s with \\s made it work. Thank you.

Comment: @ysth how would you handle names like Albrecht Dürer for this case?I do have a few names like this as well.

Comment: depends; edit your question to show output (as text, not image) of `show create table yourtablename`

Comment: @ysth names like : Aurélie, Maëlys. Any names with accented characters. How would I filter them using regex '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s.`-]' –

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename;` and `select version();`

Comment: likely something like `[^[:alnum:]\\s.`-]` but depends on ^

Answer (score 0):

You could use this expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.`-]+$
```

Explanation:

> a-z matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z
> (index 122) (case sensitive)
>
> A-Z matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z
> (index 90) (case sensitive)
>
> 0-9 matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9
> (index 57) (case sensitive)
>
> \s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>
> .`- matches a single character in the list .`- (case sensitive)
>
> $ asserts position at the end of a line

For more details you can test using this site: https://regex101.com/

Comment: from their attempt, they are looking for a regex to find invalid ones, not valid ones

Comment: replacing \s with \\s made it work. @ysth has some useful reference links which I referred [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558172/mysql-regexp-whitespace-s